# Key "3" does not produce output, but "Shift+3" still produces the hash/pound character

Tags: macos, keyboard

This is the strangest thing. When I hit the 3 key on my keyboard's vertical number row, nothing happens. But when I hold shift and hit 3, I get the pound/hash sign (#). So for some reason, 3 is not appearing, except from the numpad. I know the key works, because I can get the # character, and Javascript can get the keyCode when I press the key (tested [here](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)).

I'm running OS X, and I have an Apple keyboard attached to my MBP. I checked in System Preferences and there shouldn't be a keyboard shortcut for that key. I'm truly perplexed.

Comment: try another keyboard

Comment: Oh my. So I simply typed the 3 key on my laptop's own keyboard. First keypress did not work, then I started working normally. Now my attached keyboard also works. I still have no idea what caused this, but thank you.